# Need to correlate ps and load average

Tags: redhat, high-load, load-testing

Let's say that I have 4 CPUs. In that case, load average should not go beyond 4 for better performance, it means only 4 threads can be run at a time (i.e., only 4 should be in `R` status in `ps` output). Correct me if I'm wrong.

A Java program with multi-threaded support is running, so multiple threads will try to occupy the running state (bad programming), in this case, the load goes beyond 4, as the number of threads required by Java to run is high.

Is it possible to limit the "running state" threads of a single process at the OS level (affecting only the single process, not the entire system) to make the load average stay low?

Comment: In a word, yes. But how you do that depends on the operating system you are using, which you did not specify.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I am using RedHat 7 OS.